# How did Spider-Man get web-fluid back in his web-shooters?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man, spider-man-homecoming

In Spider-Man: Homecoming, after the plane crashes, and Peter tries to save Toomes' life, he realizes that web-fluid in his web-shooters is depleted

[image: Web shooters out of web-fluid]

Anyways, he saves him after pulling out, but tied him and all the other technology stuff using his web-shooters

[image]

[image]

**My Question is :** How did he tie up all the stuff (including Vulture), if his web-shooters were out of web-fluid?

Comment: My assumption is that his current cartridge was out, but he had brought extras that he could switch when he had a moment.

Comment: His right hand web-shooter was empty. Obviously he used his left hand shooters to pack Toomes up.

Comment: @Shreedhar Why didn't he use them at the moment shown in first pic?

Comment: @phantom42 you're right. Spider-Man always carries additional cartridges with him.

Comment: @Shreedhar Can you cite some sources?

Comment: @JaideepKhare dramatic effect?

Comment: @Shreedhar Not an explaination. BTW why a downvote?

Comment: Not MCU, but he has been cited as carrying additional webbing before: http://www.oodon.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Spider-Man-Web-Shooter-Details.png

Comment: Am I misremembering that scene? I recall him struggling to extend his arm (as in the first still above) apparently due to his injuries, and successfully firing the web a moment later.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**His Web Shooters are cartridge-based, and he could have used his other web shooter, or reloaded with a new cartridge**

Since Spider-Man just got his introduction into the MCU movies, there is very little "MCU canon" references. Then again, Spider-Man was created by Marvel, with his first comic appearance in Amazing Fantasy #15 (August 1962). From his very beginning, Spider-Man used web shooters that were fueled by cartridges.

[image: Comic Spider-Man reloads a new web cartridge]

Also in the cartoon series, there were a lot of references to Spider-Man using cartridges for his web shooters

[image: Cartoon Spider-Man reloads a new web cartridge]

The best, although indirect reference to mechanical web shooters (and therefore needing to be refilled) will be the scenes where the suit's AI mentions custom web 'settings', like ricochet web, or web grenade. Also, in the warehouse scene, you see Spidey hanging from a web hammock, and on his arm tucked behind his head, you see the bottom of his wrist, and a clear sight of his web shooter.

We already have a reference of the web shooters being mechancial, and that they run out of fluid, there was no actual reference of them being refilled (**yet**).Just wait, it's probably on the way.

**EDIT:** The original answer I've posted had come before Spider-Man: Homecoming. So now we live in a world where it has happened; Spider-Man is seen with web shooters, and reloading them, on screen. The best example is found on the ferry fight. [About 30 seconds in](https://youtu.be/ORrQKFliVLM), after Parker takes down all of the bad guys on the aft deck, the camera pans around as he gets in some Spidey dialog. There, you see him quickly reload a new cartridge in time to shoot out a web to a bad guy running through the garage deck towards him.

Comment: We do see Spidey replacing one of his spent cartridges earlier in the film, actually. It's while he's sitting on a fire escape eating his sandwich, just after leaving Happy a voicemail.